# Messages not coming to Java Camel route application in sequence

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-artemis, spring-camel, amq

The problem I am facing is very strange. My application is a Spring Boot application where I am using a Camel route to listen to AMQ 7 and then processing the message till it gets stored in a database or sent to another AMQ 7 instance. The issue is messages are consumed from AMQ via Camel but it's not maintaining the order in  application logs. This means that before the flow for first message is getting completed I could see the logs start getting printed for another message dropping into AMQ which is making it difficult to track that the logs belong to which message from AMQ. Is it a prob with AMQ or Camel routes? Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your camel route?

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be related to the camel route if the `asyncConsumer` option is enabled, see the documentation for further details https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/activemq-component.html